# How to do string combining and querying with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, tostring

How can I combine variables to a string and use the string in a where condition within a LINQ query? I have tried this:

```
query = query.Where(p => (p.Cod + p.Year + p.Count).StartsWith("BS201412"));
```

My variables are as follows:

- `Cod` is of type `string`
- `Year` is of type `short`
- `Count` is of type `int`

I have also tried this:

```
  query = query.Where(p => (p.Cod + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) p.Year)+ SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) p.Count)).StartsWith("BS201412"));
```

but because of `Year` the query is not working in both variants.

Comment: Are the 3 properties in your code the only ones in that class?  If so, you may want to override ToString so that it looks something like query.Where(p => p.ToString().StartsWith("value")).  Also is StartsWith actually what you want?  What happens if Count = 123 or Count = 12?  Should that be treated the same?

Answer (score 2):

You have many options and two of them are:

1. use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it converts automatically every parameter to string
2. use the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on the complex variable

Example:

```
string cod = "BS";
short year = 14;
int count = 100;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", cod, year, count));
Console.WriteLine(cod + year.ToString() + count.ToString());
```

The output is in both cases the same:

```
BS14100
BS14100
```

Your query line could look like this:

```
query = query
        .Where(p => String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", p.Cod, p.Year, p.Count)
        .StartsWith("BS201412"));
```

---

Because you are using LINQ2SQL some of the functions can not be used (because they can not be translated to SQL directly). You can try a different approach - it looks like you have the String you want to search for `BS201420`, so you can partition the string, convert every part to the corresponding type and write a normal query, something like this:

```
var searchFor = "BS201420";
var cod = searchFor.Substring(0, 2);
// example - use short.TryParse in your code
var year = short.Parse(searchFor.Substring(2, 4));
// example - use int.TryParse in your code
var count = int.Parse(searchFor.Substring(4,2));
query = query.Where(p => p.Cod == cod && p.Year == year && p.Count == count);
```

This should find the same result set as with the string and starts with.

Comment: Just for readability, you might want to use query syntax with a `let` expression:
`query = from q in query let key = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", p.Cod, p.Year, p.Count) where key.StartsWith("BS201412");` (Which you could also line-break if the comment field allowed it. :))

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work: `query = query.Where(p => p.Stringify().StartsWith("BS201412"));` this is LINQ to SQL (or Entities) in either case you can't use a custom function within a query.

Comment: A partial class that adds the functionality to the Entity can be created.

Comment: Examples from comments where removed.

Comment: I have also tried this: <pre> query.Where(p => String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", p.Cod, p.Year, p.Count).StartsWith("BS14100")); </pre> this exception: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: This is because the SQL server does not know about `String.Format`. Try the variant with `p.Cod + p.Year.ToString() + p.Count.ToString()` - it should work.

Comment: @user3403034 I added another option with which you can overcome the LINQ2SQL limitations.